# Trying to trigger dialogue when the space bar is clicked, and two objects are colliding

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I'm getting a NullReferenceException on OnTriggerStay. I've been going crazy trying to figure out why. I have tried to cut this down to only the relevent information. I got this code through a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=48&v=_nRzoTzeyxU (just for credits).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class MainCharacter : MonoBehaviour {
    public int limbs;

    public float speed;
    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float fire_start_time = Time.time;
    Animator animator;
    public DialogueManager dialogueManager;

    // Checking if we are grounded
    public bool isGrounded;
    public LayerMask groundLayers;

    private SpriteRenderer myRenderer;

    public Sprite[] LimbSprites;

    void Start()
    {
        dialogueManager = gameObject.GetComponent<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Dialogue dialogue = collision.GetComponent<Dialogue>();
            dialogueManager.StartDialogue(dialogue);

        }
    }

}
```

Here is my dialogue manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text nameText;
    public Text dialogueText;

    public Animator animator;

    private Queue<string> sentences;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue) {

        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", true);

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;
        sentences.Clear();

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences) {
            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence() {
        if (sentences.Count == 0) {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
        dialogueText.text = sentence;
    }

    void EndDialogue() {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", false);
    }
}
```

Here is DialogueTrigger

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue () {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);

    }
}
```

Here is Dialogue

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour {

    public string name;

    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] sentences;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your OnTriggerStay method

```
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Dialogue dialogue = collision.GetComponent<Dialogue>();
            dialogueManager.StartDialogue(dialogue);

        }
}
```

The problem is that you don't control with which object you are currently colliding, it can be any GameObject with a collider set on trigger and not just those who have a Dialog component.

I suggest adding a tag to those GameObjects or do a defensive check.

```
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "CanTalkWith")
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                {
                    Dialogue dialogue = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Dialogue>();
                    if (dialogue != null)
                    {
                        dialogueManager.StartDialogue(dialogue);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much :) This was driving me insane! You also taught me how to check if my character is on the ground haha. Much appreciated. It's all coming together

Comment: I recommend getting in the habit of using `CompareTag()` instead of `.tag ==`, as it plays with Unity's internals a little more efficiently, while accomplishing the same task just as legibly.